# I cannot select same class elements with query selector all. I use the VS code editor

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, selectors-api

In javascript file, I select same class element with query selector all like this...

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
```

In html file, I wrote like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
    <button class="button" value="rock" style="background-color: rgb(240, 20, 20)"></button>

    <button class="button" value="paper" style="background-color: rgb(20, 240, 20)"></button>
    
    <button class="button" value="scissor" style="background-color: rgb(20, 20, 240)"></button>

  </body>
</html>
```

After I select the elements, I try to console the "buttons". But what I got is nodelist(0). You can see it in following image...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jCEi.png)

I watched all the tutorial and learned how to do this. I did the exactly the same but the outcome is not what I expected. Can anyone tell me did I make a mistake or did I need to add something?

Answer (score 1):

import js script file footer.

and wait to DOM load

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
    console.log(buttons);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    
    <button class="button" value="rock" style="background-color: rgb(240, 20, 20)"></button>

    <button class="button" value="paper" style="background-color: rgb(20, 240, 20)"></button>
    
    <button class="button" value="scissor" style="background-color: rgb(20, 20, 240)"></button>
      <script src="index.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use node as array
Because all `.button` same class Name in ALl button that's why all Button are in one NodeList

you can access NodeList by indexing. just like `buttons[0]` or `buttons[1]`or `buttons[2]`

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
console.log(buttons[2])
```

this code console blue button

Comment: I aleady tried that way but it show only undefined. When I console with "buttons[0].value", it shows error.